# How to place a div, opened by bootstrap's Navbar

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap sticky navbar that contains a button, which opens a drop-down div, that contains a list of clickable links.

my Bootply(similar to jsfidlle): http://www.bootply.com/T69XCh0Vei

[image: bootstrap sticky navbar]

using CSS, I would like to position that div just under the navbar, in any reasonable screen width, including mobile.

Setting the div's position as 'relative' doesn't help me as it is contained inside the navbar which causes the navbar's height go out of scale.

code sample:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="sticky-nav-bar">
    <div class="container-fluid row">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn dropdown-toggle col-md-1" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
            <span>NAVIGATE</span>       
          </button>

            <div id="navbar-titles-id" class="hidden-xs">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-1">
                  <h5>Status</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-1">
                  <h5>Code</h5>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="visible-xs" id="navbar-xs-id">
                <div class="result-title">
                    <h2>Status Code</h2>
                </div>
            </div>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu-nav-id">
            <li><input role="link" type="button" class="btn li-max-width" onclick="scrollToElement('#anchor0')" value="LINK 0"></li>
            <li><input role="link" type="button" class="btn li-max-width" onclick="scrollToElement('#anchor1')" value="LINK 1"></li>
            <li><input role="link" type="button" class="btn li-max-width" onclick="scrollToElement('#anchor2')" value="LINK 2"></li>
            <li><input role="link" type="button" class="btn li-max-width" onclick="scrollToElement('#anchor3')" value="LINK 3"></li>
          </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Maybe try using the VW scale on the margin of the dropdown container.
ie. ul.dropdown-menu{margin-left:10vw} and using media queries as needed for smaller viewports.

Comment: @Korgrue I would prefer, if possible, to avoid placing the div at its proper position, manually, for each screen, this can get quite messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result with minimal change. Just add any custom class eg: `dropdown-pos` to `<div class="dropdown">` and give the style `position: static`.

> The problem is the `position: relative` style which is default applied
>   to `dropdown` class. Which make the dropmenu to stick at the bottom of
>   its parent element.

Check Working Demo [**Here**](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/bBEvbO)

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="sticky-nav-bar">
  <div class="container-fluid row">
    <div class="dropdown dropdown-pos">
      <button class="btn dropdown-toggle col-md-1" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
                <span>NAVIGATE</span>       
              </button>

      <div id="navbar-titles-id" class="hidden-xs">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-1">
          <h5>Status</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-1">
          <h5>Code</h5>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="visible-xs" id="navbar-xs-id">
        <div class="result-title">
          <h2>Status Code</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu-nav-id">
        <li><input role="link" class="btn li-max-width" onclick="scrollToElement('#anchor0')" value="LINK 0" type="button"></li>
        <li><input role="link" class="btn li-max-width" onclick="scrollToElement('#anchor1')" value="LINK 1" type="button"></li>
        <li><input role="link" class="btn li-max-width" onclick="scrollToElement('#anchor2')" value="LINK 2" type="button"></li>
        <li><input role="link" class="btn li-max-width" onclick="scrollToElement('#anchor3')" value="LINK 3" type="button"></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-pos{
    position: static;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the floating menu a top margin. As per your fiddle:

```
.open>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 54px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is made by class 'col-md-1',with this class,'.dropdown' div has height=0;set a height to .dropdown can fix this problem;

```
<div class="dropdown" style="height:40px">
```

or add clearfix class to it

```
<div class="dropdown clearfix">
```

Answer (score 0):

As always, you can hardcode values to accomplish desired result, but I think the best for this is to add `clearfix` as suggested to `dropdown` and remove `min-height` from `navbar` class. Dropdown menu is shown under the parent element, and navbar have greater value, so dropdown menu and navbar are overlapping. If you want to have bigger gap, just use `line-height` on navbar to vertically center elements and style elements according to that.

Working example http://www.bootply.com/giO0PF2LGs